# How to create plugin auto create page wordpress?

Tags: plugins, pages

I want a plugin can create auto page insert into database wordpress. How ?

Comment: When the page should be created?

Comment: when install plugin. I see codex only function create post is wp_insert_post, but not insert page

Comment: You can use register_activation_hook to create page on plugin activation. wp_insert_post can be used to create page. you need to pass post_type = 'page'

Comment: Please work on a solution on your own. If you have trouble with it, post your code and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The following hook is called when the plugin is activated from the dashboard.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
function myplugin_activate() {
   //create a variable to specify the details of page
   $post = array(     
             'post_content'   => 'content', //content of page
             'post_title'     =>'title', //title of page
             'post_status'    =>  'publish' , //status of page - publish or draft
             'post_type'      =>  'page'  // type of post
   );
   wp_insert_post( $post ); // creates page
}
```